# Which is correct here: "*sometime* next month" vs. "*sometimes* next month"?

Tags: word-choice, time

Are those expressions equivalent, or which one should be preferred?

For instance:

> I should finish this work **sometimes** next week

versus

> I should finish this work **sometime** next week

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although they look similar and are both adverbs, they are not equivalent.

- **Sometime** means "*someday, at some time, at some point; during, in the course of.*", and it's the word you want to use in this case.

> I should finish this work **sometime/at some time/during** next week.

As you can see, replacing it, it still makes sense.

- **Sometimes**, instead, means "*occasionally, from time to time, now and then, etc.*"

If you try to replace it now, it won't make sense:

> I should finish this work **sometimes/from time to time** next week.

This last one should be used for example to say:

> **Sometimes** I like taking a walk. `(which becomes)` **From time to time**, I like taking a walk.

Comment: @nico: you're welcome! Sometimes substituting expressions can help you to see if it was correct, but not all can be substituted as is. I mean, sometimes you must add/remove a preposition, etc...

Answer (score 2):

*sometime* means "at a single unspecified point in time."

*sometimes* means "at various unspecified points in time."

When you say "I should finish this work..." you're talking about specific work, and it's only logical that said work can only become finished at one point in time, so only "sometime" makes sense.

Comment: So, what about something that you can do several time? Can you say *I will have a beer sometimes next week?*.